# Is it a good practice to set an object to null after processing?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have scenario like this:

```
public void processData(String name,String value) {

/* line 1 */    MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();  
/* line 2 */    dto.setName(name);
/* line 3 */    dto.setValue(value);
/* line 4 */    sendThroughJMSChannel(dto);
/* line 5 */    dto = null; //As a best practice, should I do this ?

}
```

In my program after *line 4* I don't require `dto` for further processing. As a best practice, should I set `dto` to `null` as in *line 5* or ignore it?

By setting it to `null`, I'm expecting fast garbage collection. Is it correct?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, do not set local variables to `null` to hasten their collection by the GC: the compiler is smart enough to figure it out without your help; the `null` assignments will only make your code look dirty.

Non-locals are a different story: if you have a member variable that might stay around for longer than necessary, it is a good idea to set it to `null` and prevent *lingerer memory leaks*.

Answer (score 13):

It will be out of scope it self after line 4 (once method invocation is over) so not required in this case

Answer (score 0):

As already been said, compiler is smart enough for the local scope but again in the non local scope it is a lot more context specific. One needs to understand how legitimate it is to nullify the reference at a particular point. Say when using a HashMap -

```
Map<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String name = "test";             
Object o = new Object();          
entry.put(name, o);                

o = null; 
name = null; 

System.gc(); // Nothing is eligible !!! Still referenced by the Map.

Object test = entry.get("test");    // Returns the object.
```

The entry must be removed from being referenced from the HashMap first, in this scenario.